# Emacs ecb ignore certain file extensions

Tags: emacs

Is it possible to make emacs ecb (Emacs Code Browser)
not show .pyc and .pyo files in the directory browser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can customize the variable `source-file-regexps` which specifies which files are shown as source files. You can find it in the group "ecb-sources".

<kbd>M-x customize-group RET ecb-sources</kbd>

See also the ECB [documentation](http://ecb.sourceforge.net/docs/ecb_002dsources.html#ecb_002dsources).